# Difference between exclamation mark (!) and point (.) in MAGMA

Tags: math-software, magma-cas

In [this MAGMA handbook](https://www.math.uzh.ch/sepp/magma-2.19.8-cr/HandbookVolume10.pdf), I found the following code:

```
K := FiniteField(2, 160); // finite field of size 2^160
E := EllipticCurve([K!1, 0, 0, 0, K.1]);
```

There, I noted the notations K!1 and K.1, and I do not really understand what the difference is between these two. It seems like two ways of conversion of $1$ into the finite field $K$. But then it would be pretty useless to use both notations if they supposedly do the same. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: This is off-topic, because these operations are detailed in the handbook; just look them up. Also you can easily check that `K!1` and `K.1` are not the same element of the field you have defined here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ! denotes coercion, for which more information can be found here: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/9

On the other hand, K.1 picks out the first generator of K.

Consider for instance the code:

> F<x> := FiniteField(3,2); \\ F.1; \\ F!1;

With output:

```
x; \\ 1
```

So they are very much not the same (but may happen to overlap in simple cases)!